# Error: Invalid private key | Hyperledger Fabric Node SDK

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I am using the **balance transfer sample**.

I have enabled the `ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CLIENTAUTHREQUIRED=true` in orderer container.

While creating a new channel(mychannel) it was throwing error of `Handshake failed with fatal error`

After the error I configured the client

`client.setTlsClientCertAndKey(cert, key);`

```
 let adminClient = JSON.parse(
      fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, "../fabric-client-kv-org1/admin"))
    );
    logger.info(adminClient);

    client.setTlsClientCertAndKey(
      adminClient.enrollment.identity.certificate,
      adminClient.enrollment.signingIdentity
    );
```

I am importing `admin` and then using its signingIdentity and certificate to set the tls client.

Now, it is throwing error as `Invalid private key`

```
E0619 17:15:44.135000000 139448 ssl_transport_security.cc:671] Invalid private key.
E0619 17:15:44.136000000 139448 security_connector.cc:1087] Handshaker factory creation failed with TSI_INVALID_ARGUMENT.
E0619 17:15:44.137000000 139448 secure_channel_create.cc:121] Failed to create secure subchannel for secure name 'localhost:7050'
E0619 17:15:44.137000000 139448 secure_channel_create.cc:154] Failed to create subchannel arguments during subchannel creation.
2019-06-19T11:45:47.132Z - error: [Remote.js]: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpcs://localhost:7050
2019-06-19T11:45:47.133Z - error: [Orderer.js]: Orderer grpcs://localhost:7050 has an error Error: Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpcs://localhost:7050
```

What is the cause of error and Am I using the correct client certificate and key? It is confusing in docs

https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/tutorial-network-config.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the reason for the invalid private key. The signing identity is not the private key.

After registering the user, I am enrolling it and saving its private key and certificate locally.

```
 let req = {
      enrollmentID: "admin",
      enrollmentSecret: "adminpw",
      profile: "tls"
    };

    const enrollment = await caClient.enroll(req);
client.setTlsClientCertAndKey(
      enrollment.certificate,
      enrollment.key.toBytes()
    );
```